# While loop is not working in ResultSet java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

I am using the below code to get the result from a sql query:

```
try{
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME";

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        String[] commaseperatedValues ; 
        while (rs.next()) {
          //do something
           log.debug(" SetString string is  "+rs.getString(1));
            if(",".contains(rs.getString(1))){
                commaseperatedValues = rs.getString(1).split(",");
                for(String str : commaseperatedValues)
                    list.add(str);
            }else{
                list.add(rs.getString(1));
            }

        }
        }
}catch{}
```

In the logs ResultSet is printed as:

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet@f34e856
```

But it doesnt enter the while loop. From SQLDeveloper it gives results properly. I got (430) results. But while loop is not working here. Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: How do you know, that the `while` loop is not entered?

Comment: Use a debugger and check the value of `rs` before entering the loop.

Comment: do you know that your query returns at least 1 row ?

Comment: I did and i have posted the value as it is printing in the log as : org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet@f34e856 @Bucket

Comment: @diginoise yes as i said while the same query in sql developer returns 430 results

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose i have kept log statements and the log stamenets were nver printed..and the result is not expected as well

Comment: In your question you said that the result "is printed as `org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet@f34e856`" (which is obviously your result object). In your comment you said "the log stamenets were nver printed". So what is your actual problem? Both can't be true.

Comment: Your catch block has illegal syntax. How does your catch block really look in the actual code? If it's truly empty, then you need to put a logging line in there to give you information about the exception which has been caught. If any exception is generated in the try block, execution will stop and the code within the catch block will execute instead.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose i mean to say the log statements in while loop are never printed.

Comment: Are there any exceptions thrown?  and What does `rs.getFetchSize()` return ?

Comment: Looks like you are doing `System.out.println(rs)` which is not going to work. You need to loop over the result and retrieve the column values from it - those you can print. This has absolutely nothing to do with the fetch size. See the [JDBC tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) for a start

Comment: I see no expections thrown @diginoise will let you in a min about rs.getFetchSize()

Comment: @Bobulous catch block has some code in it. Its not empty

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am looping it. While looping itself i have added few log statements which are not printing which means it didnt entered the loop.

Comment: Show us the code _inside_ the loop. **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name done

Comment: `if(",".contains(rs.getString(1)))` will only be true if the `getString()` returns `","` - probably not what you intend.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes but did you see the log statement above the if condition? that should be printed right?

Comment: @diginoise I think you have the wrong idea what `getFetchSize()` returns, and what it means. Specifically the value is a hint the JDBC driver uses for the number of rows it requests from the server in a single fetch.

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely getting a result. Its the object. So the object needs to be sliced according to your database column's name.

Example:

```
String firstName = rs.getString("first_name");
```

inside the `while...` then you can print it

Comment: rs.getString("first_name"); first_anme as in the column_name?

Comment: Yes. suppose, you are expecting a result , that has name, id, phone number. then you can get those, by:                                                 
 String name =  rs.getString("name");   Int id =  rs.getInt("id");  String phone = rs.getString("phone");

Comment: as posted in the query i am just getting a particuler column results

Comment: Yes. Because you have used DISTINCT. It is what it does. It gives you the result of that very specific column.  Isn't it what you want?

Comment: Whats teh point of using something like this here?: String name = rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME"); as i am just getting results with multple rows i need to iterate over it right?